# Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio - GPT 3.5 Turbo Fine-Tuning Problem

Tags: azure, gpt-3

The error is as follows:"The intellectual property publisher for the compute is "" but the intellectual property publisher for the run configuration is "OpenAIDevault" and they must be the same. If you are using an intellectual property protected component, please make sure you are using an intellectual", I don't get how to fix it? Any suggestions?
[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2zoS.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with your setup details, reference code that can help in reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is differences between `Azure AI` and `Azure OpenAI`, the first one has also listing of those models however I experience the same problem as noted above, furthermore it is not possible to deploy even without fine-tuning.
The `Azure OpenAI`, however provides you key, endpoint and deployment (potentially also to finetune) -> that's what I have found out so far.